# Small text quest

Tags: java

This is the first small project I wanted to do for myself and make a small text adventure, i'm stuck on an error that i've been trying to solve but so far I haven't gotten any solutions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
   public static void main(String arg[])
   throws InterruptedException;
   public void disply() {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("The last thing you remember is being knocked out with a rusty pipe.");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      System.out.println("You wake up in a dark room with a locked door in front of you.");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      System.out.println("There are no items in the room.");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      System.out.println("");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      System.out.println("What wil you do? \n");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      System.out.println("--Actions--");
      System.out.println(
         "Select an Action:  \n" +
         "  1) Give up and die\n" +
         "  2) Slam your head and bleed out and die\n" +
         "  3) Scream and alert the kidnappers to come kill you\n" +
         "  4) Realize all of these options lead to death so select this to quit the text game\n"
         );
   
   
   
   
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. When asking a question, please provide a detailed explanation of your problem and an instruction to reproduce your error. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you are missing main method definition. add {} to main method

Answer (score 1):

Your main method is incorrect. `public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException;` should be

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Game().disply();
}
```

to fix the Java syntax, and to create a `Game` instance and call the method that you likely want to run.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have a syntax error on your main method this can be easily fixed by changing a semi colon to a pair of curly braces.

Before:

```
public static void main(String arg[])
   throws InterruptedException;
```

After:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException {

    }
```

Secondly, you have an error with the .sleep() method, which can be fixed by adding `throws InterruptedExecption` to your disply() method.

After:

```
public void disply() throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("The last thing you remember is being knocked out with a rusty pipe.");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("You wake up in a dark room with a locked door in front of you.");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("There are no items in the room.");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("What wil you do? \n");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("--Actions--");
        System.out.println(
                "Select an Action:  \n" +
                        "  1) Give up and die\n" +
                        "  2) Slam your head and bleed out and die\n" +
                        "  3) Scream and alert the kidnappers to come kill you\n" +
                        "  4) Realize all of these options lead to death so select this to quit the text game\n"
        );

    }
```